Allow users to edit post without logging in
I'm working on a site where non-logged in users are able to submit their posts. It's easy to do on front end, however, when the posts need to be edited, it's a completely different story.
So, is there a way to allow non-logged in users to edit the post without logging in (for example through a special link sent to the email address after post submission from front-end)?

This sounds really risky.  I guess you could set up a temporary URL with some randomized strings, save the parameter of the URL into a DB table, then when the user clicks the link in an email you would verify if that string exists - maybe try and use their IP address to validate that the request is coming from the same place... ...you'll definitely want to sanitize whatever users are inputting to ensure you're not exposing the site.
